# Customize Ubuntu LiveCD 16.04 desktop background

Tags: 16.04, live-cd

I am chrooted into the root directory of my Ubuntu LiveCD filesystem and want to know how to change the desktop background. I have tried the gsettings command but it gives me an error about not having X11 running.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the folder of the default backgrounds `/usr/share/backgrounds/`, copy the image over that you would like to have as the default background, rename the new image `warty-final-ubuntu.png`, and then delete the original default background.

Comment: thanks yes this will work, was wondering if there was another way where i could use my own filename